# Position Action Buttons in Subform

Tags: acumatica

Is there any way I can move action buttons from the main form of the page to a sub form on a page as shown in the following screen shot?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All actions will appear on main toolbar by default. You could hide them from there by using a < px: PXDSCallbackCommand Name="YOURACTIONNAME" Visible="False" CommitChanges="true" >< /px:PXDSCallbackCommand >. Then you could add your action to your Tab/Grid ActionBar. On AR303000-Customers you could see an example on Contacts Tab.

Comment: Is there an example that exists with the actions being assigned to a form vs a grid? If not, I can suffice with putting them above the grid instead of the form the selector is on.

Comment: Yes, you could review AP303000(InsertDefaultData button) on how to add it to form as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly for the grid! One thing, however: the SkinID must be set to something. For me, the appropriate ID is Primary since I am just using custom buttons on it. Thanks!